# StoreKit review request weird tap gesture behavior on alert

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storekit

I am trying to implement the review request on an app, I first ask if the user enjoy the app and if he says yes I launch the review request, everything goes well until I try to communicate with the alert, only a (very) long (and quite strong) press on the dismiss button will make it triggered, and I can't trigger the stars button (I guess because I am in development maybe?)

I can't try on a simulator as the project I am working on doesn't launch for several reasons, I have this issue using an iPhone 11, iOS 16.0.2, Xcode 14.0.1

I am using Cocoapods

Here is the code I use to launch the request review (I can't create a snippet for this as I am working on a project that has many implementation)

```swift
// Launch review
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    .first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found why I had this issue, in the project I am working on, the previous developer added a DragGesture on the main view container like that :

The gesture

```swift
let drag = DragGesture().onEnded {
      if $0.translation.width < -100 && navigationCoordinator.sideMenuIsOpen {
        withAnimation {
          navigationCoordinator.sideMenuIsOpen = false
        }
      }
    }
```

The implementation

```swift
View
.gesture(drag)
```

So this was taking the priority on all, when I saw that I knew it was the issue, I had 2 solutions, delete it or replacing it with :

```swift
View
.simultaneousGesture(drag)
```

As this feature part was not used anymore I decided to delete it